# Is there a term for "neutral" in the vein of "pros and cons"

Tags: single-word-requests

Pros means positive aspects 
Cons means negative aspects 
____ means neutral aspects

Is there a word to fill that blank?

Comment: In a list of pros and cons, the neutral aspects are “***left off the list***”

Comment: In [*binary*](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+binary) contexts (like "pros and cons"), a third possibility (and beyond) is inexistent.

Answer (score 5):

No. There is not.

However, the terms Pro and Con have come to have slightly different meanings in different contexts. Their origin is from the Latin and in that context means arguments for and against something [https://www.lexico.com/explore/pros-and-cons-origin]. In that context, there is no grammatically equivalent Latin construct now in English.

However, in modern English (particularly American English) "pro" and "con" are used more broadly. As other answers have noted, something which is not "for" or "against" something else (note the generalization beyond logical or rhetorical arguments) might be neutral, non-impactful, trivial, irrelevant, or any number of other things.

Answer (score 2):

**Pros** and **Cons** are essentially opinion based arguments. They are arguments for or against something. You can use "**Neutral(ities)**", "**Noncommittal**",  or even just "**Notes**" as other words to describe a category/group/list of neutral aspects for the sake of argument or further consideration.

> **Pros** means positive aspects
>   **Cons** means negative aspects
>   **Noncommittal**
>   means neutral aspects

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pro

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Cons

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/neutrality

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/noncommittal

Comment: I tend to think of non-committal as an attitude held by a person *about* some topic.  The topic itself can’t commit or not commit to anything.

Comment: Good day, Jim. So it is with pros and cons, and I do see you are noncommittal about the answer. I would think "Neutrals" could be used in the given context, but it might still confuse. But, alas, this is a question and answer exchange. The topic was asked as a question, and has been given a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

The pro-ness or con-ness of a particular quality is always measured in respect to a stated goal or purpose.  If something is neither pro nor con in respect to that goal or purpose, it is **irrelevant** in respect to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that they are **nonfactors** (also spelled **non-factors**) in the process of making a decision.  [Cambridge defines this as:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/non-factor)

> a fact, situation, or person that does not influence the result of something

Answer (score -1):

If you say "pros, cons, and nons," that would be nice and catchy. Maybe with a little note to explain. This would work for any register lower than academic paper or press release.

Comment: _Non_ just sounds like a different type of _con_.